# Should I go with attaching MDF file to SQL Express or a real deployment script to SQL Server?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, deployment, mdf

I am building a blog-like publishing system on ASP.NET 4.0 (with EF 4.0) that I want to be **very easily deployable/backupable** in the *first* place. I am at a decision point of whether making the system to create a database in an SQL Server and use that (traditionally), or have a App_Data MDF file in the site and just attach to that one with SQL Express. I *know* the memory/size limitations of Express editions, and I won't be hitting the limits as this is *not* a performance-critical business application or any serious stuff. Just a simple CMS with blogs/writings/photos (actual photos are NOT saved in database, just their paths are saved in MDF) and that's it. I see no problem using MDF, but I'm not an expert on the topic too as I've never worked/created a website using MDF file. I always deployed on the SQL Server, but I don't want to deal with users/roles/permissions and the last thing that I want to have a user having installation problems due to database settings.

What should I go with? Any problems that I would face with MDF? Recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**IF** you use SQL Server Express - which is a **server** - I would always opt for a "real" database approach: attach your database to the server, access it by its database name, deploy SQL scripts to update it.

That "attach DB from file path" always seemed like a half-baked and rather messy kludge to me.....

If you don't need that kind of power - investigate [SQL Server Compact Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/compact.aspx) which is a one-file only, in-process database. It has its limitations - no stored procedures, doesn't support certain data types like `VARCHAR(MAX)` or `XML` - but for easier scenarios, it's perfect and easy to use - just deploy it along your app. It's single-user, e.g. you don't share the data between several clients, it's a local store for each user/app on its own

Comment: First of all, Compact Edition is not suitable.. It seems a bit crappy, and I don't think it will play well with EF.

I understand the way you feel about Express Edition and "attach DB" part, but it just makes my app more portable, for example while moving the system, one would just copy all the files and that's it. No external setup or backup or anything. That's what I actually want (just like ASP.NET web.config files, they are in website directory and have all the settings of the website). I am curious about some unforeseen circumstances of using Express/attach method, if there are any.

Comment: @can poyrazoglu: well, you asked for opinions - this is mine. BTW: SQL Server Compact 4.0 is definitely **NOT** crappy, you never explain why it's "unsuitable", and it does play very well with EF 4.0

Comment: I respect (and consider) you opinion it wasn't something like offensive or anything (although it may sound that way - I agree). Almost everywhere on the net I read Express is taking the place of CE, don't use CE and move on with Express. That's why I said that. It also has a different format and not everything is supported, and even though I may not need the unsupprted operations right now, I may need them in the future and it will be harder to change everything then. Bottomline: I want to use SQL Server or SQL Server Express, but not CE, because of the reasons that I've stated.

Comment: @can poyrazoglu: OK - fair enough. But again: I don't like the "attach-this-MDF-on-the-fly" approach, I would **always** use a "real" server approach - you have a server, you attach the database, and the clients just talk to the server and use the database name - they're totally oblivious about the files, where they are, what they're called etc.

Comment: Well what is your reason for always using a real DB instead of a file? If that's because of working on big, commercial (or at least more business oriented) projects, I see. I'm just wondering if there will be any issues on using Express (other than the CPU/Memory/Size limitations that I already know).

Comment: Ok, as I've got no more answers I'm answering this my own as I concluded there's nothing wrong with a Express/MDF file. Or I'll be putting an option and provide both, and control it from one centralized system. Thank you anyway.